# Laravel problema con los jobs

Tags: laravel, jobs

Tengo un listener que escucha un evento. El evento es cuando el usuario rellena un formulario de contacto y el controlador correspondiente lo persiste en la tabla. El listener es el siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Mail\ContactMails;
use App\Events\ContactWasSaved;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendMail implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(ContactWasSaved $event)
    {
        Mail::send(new ContactMails($event->contact));
    }
}
```

Como veis, hago uso de `implements ShouldQueue` para que no envíe el correo, sino que lo encole para enviarlo después. Estoy usando para las queues el `database`.

Cuando escribo `php artisan queue:work --tries=3` la tarea encolada se ejecuta perfectamente, y el correo se envía en segundo plano. Lo estoy viendo con Mailtrap, y todo funciona bien.

Ahora cambio el escenario, para que el listener llame a un job. El listener me queda así:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\ContactWasSaved;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use App\Jobs\SendContactMail;

class SendMail
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(ContactWasSaved $event)
    {
        SendContactMail::dispatch($event);
    }
}
```

Y el job me queda así:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

use App\Events\ContactWasSaved;
use App\Mail\ContactMails;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendContactMail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(ContactWasSaved $event)
    {
        Mail::send(new ContactMails($event->contact));
    }
}
```

El encolado lo hace. Cuando se persiste el mensaje, el listener llama al job, y este encola la tarea en la tabla `jobs`. Y aquí viene el problema. Cuando tecleo en la consola `php artisan queue:work --tries=3` lo intenta las tres veces y falla, y la tarea pasa a la tabla `failed_jobs`. Es como si la tarea grabada desde el job no pudiera ejecutarse, y no sé por qué. Como veis, importo todas las clases necesarias. ¿Alguien sabe cual es el problema? Estoy usando laravel 5.8.

Por si os dice algo, en el campo `payload` de la queue que sí funciona se almacena esto:

```
{"displayName":"App\\Listeners\\SendMail","job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":null,"delay":null,"timeout":null,"timeoutAt":null,"data":{"commandName":"Illuminate\\Events\\CallQueuedListener","command":"O:36:\"Illuminate\\Events\\CallQueuedListener\":7:{s:5:\"class\";s:27:\"App\\Listeners\\SendMail\";s:6:\"method\";s:6:\"handle\";s:4:\"data\";a:1:{i:0;O:29:\"App\\Events\\ContactWasSaved\":2:{s:7:\"contact\";O:45:\"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier\":4:{s:5:\"class\";s:19:\"App\\Visitorscontact\";s:2:\"id\";i:8;s:9:\"relations\";a:0:{}s:10:\"connection\";s:6:\"sqlite\";}s:6:\"socket\";N;}}s:5:\"tries\";N;s:9:\"timeoutAt\";N;s:7:\"timeout\";N;s:6:\"\u0000*\u0000job\";N;}"}}
```

En cambio, en el de la que no funciona se almacena mucho menos, así:

```
{"displayName":"App\\Jobs\\SendContactMail","job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":null,"delay":null,"timeout":null,"timeoutAt":null,"data":{"commandName":"App\\Jobs\\SendContactMail","command":"O:25:\"App\\Jobs\\SendContactMail\":7:{s:6:\"\u0000*\u0000job\";N;s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";N;s:15:\"chainConnection\";N;s:10:\"chainQueue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";N;s:7:\"chained\";a:0:{}}"}}
```

Es como si estuviera incompleta, o le faltase algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a utilizar el helper `dispatch`. En el segundo caso (el que te falla), se supone que `$event` contiene los datos del contacto, como un objeto de la clase del modelo grabado. Estos llegan del evento, si el primer ejemplo te está funcionando como dices.

En el listener del segundo ejemplo pon así el método `handle()`:

```
public function handle(ContactWasSaved $event)
{
    dispatch(new SendContactMails($event->contact));
}
```

Ahora vamos al job. Lo primero, quita la siguiente línea:

```
use App\Events\ContactWasSaved;
```

No te hace ninguna falta, y estás empleando recursos que no necesitas.
En el job debes usar el contructor. En conjunto, te debe quedar así:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

use App\Mail\ContactMails;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendContactMail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $contact

    public function __construct($contact)
    {
        $this->contact = $contact;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Mail::send(new ContactMails($this->contact));
    }
}
```

Lo que hace el helper `dispatch()` es que llama al constructor del job, y le pasa `$contact`, que es de la clase del objeto que has persistido en la base de datos.
Después, de forma transparente a ti, ejecuta el `handle()` del job. Esto pone la tarea en la tabla `jobs`, y la pone correctamente.

Cuando ejecutes `php artisan queue:work --tries=3` se envían los correos a la primera. Comprobado.

Comment: Funciona perfecto. Gracias por la explicación.